# sql how to check multiple data existed in db

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Let's say I have the following table.

[image]

Given 3 user names and  one company name, I need to check if user1 with the given company name, user2 with the same given company name and user3 with the same given company name all are in the table. If they are all in the table, my program returns ture. If one of them is not in the table, it returns false.

For example:

- given Users A, B, E and company walmart, my program should return
  false.
- given Users C, D, E and company google, my program should return
  true.

What is the most efficient sql to accomplish it?
What I can think of now is that check each user with the given company once.

```
e.g. 
   select * from [table] where user = '[given user1]' 
                 and company = '[given company name]'

   select * from [table] where user = '[given user2]' 
                 and company = '[given company name]'

   select * from [table] where user = '[given user3]' 
                 and company = '[given company name]'
```

Totally i will need to access the db 3 times for each check. I do not think this is a good way.

P.S. I am using SQL SERVER for this, but I prefer using normal/generic sql statement which can fit to most different databases if possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most SQL server products support sending a batch of SQL as one transaction, and most SQL server products compile and cache similar queries very efficiently. So there is nothing wrong with sending three queries if that leads to simpler to understand code in the long term. Think of the next person!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MIN()` and `CASE` to do this:

```
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN company = 'walmart' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END)
FROM  Table1
WHERE users IN ('a','b','e')
--False

SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN company = 'google' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END)
FROM  Table1
WHERE users IN ('c','d','e')
--True
```

If the values for comparison were stored in a table you could use the same with a `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a case:

```
 select CASE  when user = '[given user1]' and company = '[given company name]' then "true"  end as [company name], CASE  when user = '[given user2]' and company = '[given company name]' then "true"  end as [company name2]
    from [table]
```

You can do this for as many company name as you want.  And you can always CONCAT the result to show both the user and company, instead of just the company in this example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Company = @Company AND UserName = @UserName1)
             AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Company = @Company AND UserName = @UserName2)
             AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Company = @Company AND UserName = @UserName3)
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 
        END AS HasAll3
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume if a user is listed with more than one company, you still want `TRUE` returned if all are listed with the target company. Simply query the table for the company and user in the list. If you get the correct number of hits, that is `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`. I don't know how you pass the users to the code or if there can be a varying number of them, so I'll just hard-code the values and you can work out the particulars. <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b895c/7/0)</kbd>

```
select  case when count(*) = 3 then 1 else 0 end as OutCome
from    table1
where   Company = 'google'
--    and User in( 'A', 'B', 'C' )  --> should return 0 (false)
--    and User in( 'C', 'D', 'E' )  --> should return 1 (true)
--    and User in( 'D', 'E', 'F' )  --> should return 0 (false)
```

If it's possible the same user can be listed with a company more than once, you'll need to add 'distinct' to the count.

Edit: I forgot to show that this will work even if a user is "registered" with more than one company: <kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33b6e4/2/0)</kbd>